# Azure CreateVM Deployment No target URI is specified for the image

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine

I am trying to creating vm using the azure service management restapi. It is working fine if I choose my own images which i have created against my account. When I choose other images which are publicly available i am getting the following error.

```
No target URI is specified for the image fb83b3509582419d99629ce476bcb5c8__SQL-Server-2014CTP2-CU1-12.0.1736.0-Evaluation-ENU-WS2012R2-CY13SU12.
```

With the following the xml I have to create vm:

```
<Deployment xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/windowsazure" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <Name>azure4569033333</Name>
    <DeploymentSlot>Production</DeploymentSlot>
    <Label>YXp1cmU0NTY5MDMzMzMz</Label>
    <RoleList>
        <Role>
            <RoleName>azure4569033333</RoleName>
            <RoleType>PersistentVMRole</RoleType>
            <ConfigurationSets>
                <ConfigurationSet i:type="WindowsProvisioningConfigurationSet">
                    <ConfigurationSetType>WindowsProvisioningConfiguration</ConfigurationSetType>
                    <ComputerName>azure4569033333</ComputerName>
                    <AdminPassword>Pass!admin123</AdminPassword>
                    <AdminUsername>admin12</AdminUsername>
                </ConfigurationSet>
                <ConfigurationSet i:type="NetworkConfigurationSet">
                    <ConfigurationSetType>NetworkConfiguration</ConfigurationSetType>
                    <InputEndpoints>
                        <InputEndpoint>
                            <LocalPort>3389</LocalPort>
                            <Name>Remote Desktop</Name>
                            <Port>3389</Port>
                            <Protocol>tcp</Protocol>
                        </InputEndpoint>
                    </InputEndpoints>
                </ConfigurationSet>
            </ConfigurationSets>
            <OSVirtualHardDisk>
                <SourceImageName>fb83b3509582419d99629ce476bcb5c8__SQL-Server-2014CTP2-CU1-12.0.1736.0-Evaluation-ENU-WS2012R2-CY13SU12</SourceImageName>
                <MediaLink>https://portalvhdsd4lc8tzn260zd.blob.core.windows.net/vhds/fb83b3509582419d99629ce476bcb5c8__SQL-Server-2014CTP2-CU1-12.0.1736.0-Evaluation-ENU-WS2012R2-CY13SU12.vhd</MediaLink>
            </OSVirtualHardDisk>
            <RoleSize>ExtraSmall</RoleSize>
        </Role>
    </RoleList>
</Deployment>
```

Comment: @GauravMantri - would it be better to simply mark this question as a duplicate of the one you referenced?

Comment: @Murthy - not sure if you posted your real xml file in your question or if you modified it to obscure the real stuff, but assuming it's the former: It's probably not a good practice to include an actual admin username and password. If that stuff is just made up / obscured, then kindly ignore this comment.

Comment: Thanks for the information, Now its working fine. Problem is we need to change order of the xml tags medialink first followed by SourceImageName